# Dictionary Initialization with uniqingKeysWith, anonymous closure

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to understand the uniqingKeysWith initializer for dictionaries but encountering some problems when attempting to use an anonymous closure to specify which value in the tuple to use as unique keys.

```
let pairsWithDuplicateKeys = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 4)]
let dictionary = Dictionary(pairsWithDuplicateKeys, uniquingKeysWith: {$0.0})
```

This is giving me the error "Contextual closure type '(Int, Int) throws -> Int' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body", and I've experimented with adding arguments but I can't figure out what the other argument is that it is refering to.

The non anonymized version below works fine but i'd like to understand the anonymized version.

```
let dictionary = Dictionary(pairsWithDuplicateKeys, uniquingKeysWith: {(key, value) in key})
```

Comment: There is two arguments for every duplicated key there will be two values, first and last. You pass whatever value you want to be kept.

Answer (score 0):

The `closure` in **`init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`** identifies the *value of the duplicate keys*.

```
let pairsWithDuplicateKeys = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 4)]
let dict = Dictionary(pairsWithDuplicateKeys) { (first, _) -> Int in
    return first
}
```

**Output:**

```
print(dict) //["a": 1, "b": 2]
```

**Another Example:**

If you want to add the *values of the duplicate keys*, the `closure` goes like,

```
let dict = Dictionary(pairsWithDuplicateKeys) { (first, last) -> Int in
    return first + last
}
print(dict) //["a": 4, "b": 6]
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init).